# Save row in %ROWTYPE and delete it efficiently afterwards?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

This is how I do it currently:

```
DECLARE tmp message%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN;
SELECT * INTO tmp FROM [...]
DELETE FROM message m WHERE m.id = tmp.id;
END;
```

I'm afraid that the db will do two queries here: One for doing the `SELECT` and one for the `DELETE`. In case this is true - can I make this more efficient somehow? After all the row that should be deleted was already found in the `SELECT` query.

N.b. I'm eventually storing something from the `SELECT` query and return it from the function. The above is just simplified.

Comment: Yes you can use left join in the delete statement and can do in single statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from message m
using (
    select *
    from ...
) s
where m.id = s.id
returning s.*
```

Comment: This works but I don't quite understand what the "using" part is doing since in the postgres documentation it is mentioned that "USING is a shorthand notation: it takes a comma-separated list of column names, which the joined tables must have in common, and forms a join condition specifying equality of each of these pairs of columns." (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-table-expressions.html) But you are passing a query to "USING" instead of columns.

Comment: @ben The `using` you mention is for joins. This one is a list of table expressions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases you do not even need a subquery.

If your secret first query *only involves the same table*:

```
DELETE FROM message m
WHERE  m.id = <something>
RETURNING m.*;          -- or what you need from the deleted row.
```

If your secret first query *involves one or more additional tables*:

```
DELETE FROM message m
USING  some_tbl s
WHERE  s.some_column = <something>
AND    m.id = s.id
RETURNING m.id, s.foo;  -- you didn't define ...
```

#### Solution for actual query (after comments)

An educated guess, to delete the oldest row (smallest `timestamp`) from each set with identical `id`:

```
DELETE FROM message m
USING (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
          id, timestamp
   FROM   message
   WHERE  queue_id = _queue_id
   AND    source_client_id = _source_client_id
   AND   (target_client_id IN (-1, _client_id))
   ORDER  BY id, timestamp
   ) sub
WHERE m.id = sub.id
AND   m.timestamp = sub.timestamp
RETURNING m.content
INTO  rv;
```

Or, if `(id, timestamp)` is `UNIQUE`, `NOT EXISTS` is probably faster:

```
DELETE FROM message m
WHERE  queue_id = _queue_id
AND    source_client_id = _source_client_id
AND    target_client_id IN (-1, _client_id)
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   message
   WHERE  queue_id = _queue_id
   AND    source_client_id = _source_client_id
   AND    target_client_id IN (-1, _client_id)
   AND    id = m.id
   AND    timestamp < m.timestamp
   ) sub
WHERE  m.id = sub.id
RETURNING m.content
INTO   rv;
```

More about `DISTINCT ON` and selecting "the greatest" from each group:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If performance is your paramount objective, look to the last chapter ...

Aside: `timestamp` is a basic type name in Postgres and a reserved word in standard SQL. Don't use it as identifier.

#### Solution in comment below, audited:

```
DELETE FROM message m
USING (
   SELECT id
   FROM   message
   WHERE  queue_id = _queue_id
   AND    target_client_id IN (client_id, -1)
   ORDER  BY timestamp
   LIMIT  1
   ) AS tmp
WHERE  m.id = tmp.id
RETURNING m.content
INTO rv;
```

`INTO ...` only makes sense inside a plpgsql function, of course.
An index on `(queue_id, timestamp)` makes this fast - possibly even a partial index with the condition `WHERE target_client_id IN (client_id, -1)` (depends).

Comment: The query does only involve the message table only indeed. However it is structured like so `DELETE FROM message WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (timestamp) id FROM message WHERE message.queue_id = _queue_id AND message.source_client_id = _source_client_id AND (message.target_client_id = -1 OR message.target_client_id = _client_id) ORDER BY timestamp ASC) RETURNING content INTO rv;` I don't think one can do without the subquery in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @ben: Right, this needs a subquery. However, `SELECT DISTINCT ON (timestamp) id ... ORDER BY timestamp` doesn't make sense. Can you add the query you have now and explanation what it's supposed to do *exactly* to your question? Which ID from each set of identical timestamps do you want to delete?

Comment: @ben: A typical query would be to delete "the oldest row per `id`". Is that what you actually want?

Comment: Almost. `id` is unique. I want to delete the oldest row which satisfies the WHERE condition.

Comment: Whoops I just realized that `DISTINCT ON` hardly makes any sense on a unique field. I started over and came up with: `DELETE FROM message m USING (SELECT * FROM message WHERE message.queue_id = _queue_id AND (message.target_client_id = client_id OR message.target_client_id = -1) ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1) AS tmp WHERE m.id = tmp.id RETURNING m.content INTO rv;` Sorry that I did not give you sufficient information right away. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @ben: Yes, for a single row, `ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1` makes sense now - and is typically fast with index support. I added an audited version to my answer and a bit about indexes.

Comment: Wow I even had the index you proposed already created! At least one thing I did not do wrong :) Your help and your answer is great. I changed the accepted answer to yours now since it is more extensive - even without the parts which are specific to my query.